# Does logstash filter runs in sequence?

Tags: ruby, filter, logstash

So we have this logstash configuration with filter similar to this: (I excluded the output)
So I was wondering if the mutate should come first before I run my ruby code to anonymize the fields.
The anonymizer ruby is the ruby script that will anonymize.

```
input {
    http {
        port => 5045
        host => "0.0.0.0"
        add_field => { "category" => "client" }
    }
}

# The filter part of this file is commented out to indicate that it is optional.
filter {

        # the following line will create 1 additional copy of each document (i.e. including the original, 2 in total)
        # the copy will have a "type" field added only if the category is client.
        if [category] == "client" {
            clone {
                clones => ["anonym"]
            }
            # anonymized the field(s) of the cloned document through anonymizer.rb
            if [type] == "anonym" {
                ruby {
                    path => "/<path>/anonymizer.rb"
                    script_params => {
                        "key" => "<logstash_fingerprint_key>"
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        # update sample_schema_v1 to sample_schema_v2
        if [schema] == "sample_schema_v1" {
            mutate {
                update => { "schema" => "sample_schema_v2" }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: the filters are run in sequence, from top to bottom. So with how it's currently configured, the ruby filter would be executed before the mutate filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is executed in sequence.
Tested and verified.